# Putting button between Container and scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I have this design (Grey: Container's color, Dark grey: Scaffold's color)
I want to the button to be like sticking out from the Container. Is there any way to done this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Stack (widget on z-index) your button and the scaffold, play with Center/Align widget to center the bottom on the bottom center :

```
Container(
  child: Stack(
    children : [
      Scaffold(...),
      Button(...)
    ]
  )
)
```